# how to convert string to html DOM in javascript (template tolerant)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, template-engine

I try to convert a string like

```
<div name="{{hello}}"><br/>{{world}}</div>
```

in to a html dom or similar structure which could allow me to identify all these model placeholders' position.

But after trying the

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = "<div name="{{hello}}"><br/>{{world}}</div>"
```

It does not work.

Is there any js library to help me do the parsing?

Comment: You'll have to employ a template mechanism of some sort. Where do you expect the value of "hello" to come from?

Comment: Additionally to the remark of @Pointy, I think there is an error in the second line of your JS. You could try to use single quotes around **{{hello}}**:

    `el.innerHTML = "<div name='{{hello}}'><br/>{{world}}</div>"`

Hope it helps.

Comment: What about a regex or a simple string replace solution? It really depends on where your values are coming from (as Pointy mentioned)

Comment: You didn't escape the quotes, try: el.innerHTML = "<div name=\"{{hello}}\"><br/>{{world}}</div>"

Comment: thanks @T_G, I made a silly mistake about the double quote. After change it to single quote. This works

Comment: Just for the question. I am not here try to do some template engine work. Instead I want to sort of parse and analysis the template structure for further parsing.